# Search for multiple patterns using regex (and)

Tags: python, regex

I want to search for multiple patterns using python regex. In general I am reading data from the log file, line by line and searching for a pattern. If it matches I am extracting timestamp from that line. I have problem with first part. Right now reading is done in done in more pythonic way (I belive):

```
app_name = "example"
pid = 12341234
txt ="Mar 22 20:20:52.372          App1      0      Loginfo:  Application was started (example, PID: 12341234)"

if "Application was started" and pid and app_name in txt:
    print("Match found") # Prints found
else:
    print("Match not found")
```

It works fine but I was requested to use regex instead. I did some tries but the problem is that I am looking for specific data to be match (I do not want to match any PID in range 0-PID_MAX but a specific value):

```
app_name = "example"
pid = 12341234
txt ="Mar 22 20:20:52.372          App1      0      Loginfo:  Application was started (example, PID: 12341234)"

search_str = re.compile(f"/(Application was started)({app_name}),({pid})/")
if search_str.match(txt):
    print("Match found")
else:
    print("Match not found") # Prints not found
```

I do not know how can I use regex with AND to match all the values in that string?

Comment: python regexes do not use `/.../` delimiters. Plus `match` only matches at the start of the input, you probably need `search`

Comment: Your first code is not working properly: you're only checking that app_name is found in txt, together with the existence of "Application was started" and pid value, which is always true.

Comment: the expression has AND logic between terms _implicitly_. Your question does not make sense. (FOO) "AND" (BAR), "AND" (BAZ) looks like this in regex: (FOO)(BAR),(BAZ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need to escape parenthesis `\(...\)` and denote optional whitespaces `\s*` in regex pattern, then apply `pattern.search` for a quick check for match:

```
txt ="Mar 22 20:20:52.372          App1      0      Loginfo:  Application was started (example, PID: 12341234)"

pat = re.compile(fr"Application was started \({app_name},\s*PID:\s*{pid}\)")
if pat.search(txt):
    print("Match found")
else:
    print("Match not found")
```